# Basic Grepping/Sedding a part of output

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, grep

I need to remove the "+0x10" part, but the numbers could change (more digits) so I can't really always remove 5 chars from the back.

```
something -- printf@plt+0x10
```

The pattern is always "plt+" and then a hex number. I want it to look like this:

```
something -- printf@plt
```

Just without the "+0x10". I'm a bash beginner so please just bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
s='something -- printf@plt+0x10'
sed 's/^\(.*\)+0x[0-9]*$/\1/' <<< "$s"
something -- printf@plt
```

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter substitution can do this:

```
$ my_var="printf@plt+0x10"
$ echo "${my_var%%+0*}"
printf@plt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bash [substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal):

```
$ string="something -- printf@plt+0x10"
$ echo "${string%+*}"
something -- printf@plt
```